# Need help calling a function

Tags: jquery, function

I have a beginner and having trouble having the follow code run. When I hit the reset button the `draw()` function I defined does not seem to run/produce any output. The previous grid is erased but the new one is not created in its place.

I cannot seem to figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css"/>
        <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "JS/jquery.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Etch-A-Sketch</h1>
        <h3>Cameron Watson</h3>
        <div id='container'></div>
        <div class='divbut'>RESET</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
#container {    
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 720px;
    width: 720px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0;
}
.grid {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    float: left;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
.divbut {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 45px;
    width: 65px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    draw(16);

    $('.grid').hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#00ffff");
    });

    $(".divbut").click(function(){
        $('div').remove('.grid');
        draw(16);
    });
});

function draw(count){
    for (x = 0; x < count; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < count; y++) {
            $('<div>').addClass('grid').appendTo('#container');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Why you have wrote `**` in jquery part? Just for highlighting for us?

Comment: Secondly, you should use `$('div.grid').remove();` instead of `$('div').remove('.grid');` otherwise it will gonna remove all div elements.

Comment: Yeah just highlighting - it's not in the original code., Thanks for advice about the remove() statement. Fixed that up, but still not loading the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you remove the original `.grid` element which the `hover` event was bound to. When you create the new `.grid` elements, the event is no longer bound. To solve this you need to use a delegated event handler:

```
$('#container').on('mouseenter', '.grid', function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#00ffff");
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/t1761dvy/)

You would have to hook to the `mouseeenter` event in this case as `hover` is not a standard event (it's a combined usage of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`).

Also note that, as stated by @hmd, you should call remove directly on the  `$('.grid')` elements:

```
$(".divbut").click(function() {
    $('.grid').remove();
    draw(16);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Working as intended now.

Comment: No problem, glad to help